Unable to open file on Mac
I'm unable to open the file on Finder. It says App can't be opened.
I've checked security and privacy but there's nothing there.
I've tried this on the terminal but won't work. Any ideas?
% cd "/Users/pakovega/Downloads/Sound Banks Bundle 2024.10 (macOS) [Arturia]/Arturia.Sound.Banks.bundle-2024.10-osx.app"
% 
% chmod +x "/Users/pakovega/Downloads/Sound Banks Bundle 2024.10 (macOS) [Arturia]/Arturia.Sound.Banks.bundle-2024.10-osx.app"
% chmod +x "/Users/pakovega/Downloads/Sound Banks Bundle 2024.10 (macOS) [Arturia]/Arturia.Sound.Banks.bundle-2024.10-osx.app"
% sudo chmod +x "/Users/pakovega/Downloads/Sound Banks Bundle 2024.10 (macOS) [Arturia]/Arturia.Sound.Banks.bundle-2024.10-osx.app"
Password:
%


Have you just tried right-click > Open followed by the confirmation dialog?

Why not start at the top and show us how far you have gotten following the FAQ from the vendor of that software?

https://support.arturia.com/hc/en-us/articles/5723552397468-Activate-and-install-from-the-Arturia-Software-Center-ASC

If you edit some details in the question, it will be reviewed to be reopened for other answers.
